# Copy running config in one line

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios

I want to make a script to copy the running config of a switch 4506 in one line. 
So far, I see two option :

**copy run tftp:**

```
sw#copy run tftp://10.0.0.1/cfg.cfg
Address or name of remote host [10.0.0.1]? 
Destination filename [cfg.cfg]?
```

Cons: need confirmation, press enter.

Info : I have define the `ip tftp source-interface Vlan10` with management vlan to have connectivity.

or

**show running-config | redirect tftp://10.0.0.1/run-R1.cfg**

```
sw#show running-config | redirect tftp://10.0.0.1/run-R1.cfg
.....
%Error opening tftp://10.0.0.1/run-R1.cfg (Timed out)
sw#sh ip route 10.0.0.1 
% Subnet not in table
```

Cons: the ip source of the redirect is an private IP 172.16.0.2 due this is a transit subnet. So no connectivity with the outgoing interface IP but connectivity with the managment subnet. as you can see below.

```
sw#ping 10.0.0.1 source vlan 10    
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.0.0.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of 172.16.0.2 
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
sw#ping 10.0.0.1 source vlan 11
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.0.0.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
Packet sent with a source address of <Public_IP> 
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 4/6/8 ms
sw#
```

`ip tftp source-interface Vlan10` does not help with `redirect`

Questions :
- Is there the possibility of no confirmation copy with 'copy run tftp:' ?
- How can I define for all packet sourced on switch should be sourced with a defined IP ?

Comment: Where does the requirement come from that it has to be single line. There might exist option to remedy that problem.

Comment: We have a provisioning system, we can enter commands on a webgui to execute on devices. We would like to perform backup before or after provisioning ports.This is actually for 4506, updated. I've already thought about the 'archive' IOS capability but we want to control this.

Comment: Is it in-house system? Or some known system? It might be possible to punch in \n or \r\n in place of 'enter'.

Comment: @cdq74cn, configure with `ip tftp source-interface Vlan10` to source your tftp correctly... then `show running-config | redirect tftp://10.0.0.1/run-R1.cfg` should work

Comment: @MikePennington, already configured and didn't work, as described.

Comment: @ytti, in-house system. Let me check Monday with the System Team.

Comment: @cdq74cn, are you using vrfs?  BTW, it is not clear that you tried `ip tftp source-interface Vlan10` with your redirect option

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try turning file prompt behavior to quiet.

```
6506(config)#file prompt quiet
6506(config)#end
6506#copy run tftp://192.168.1.1/file.txt
.....
```

Comment: That's a hidden hack command ! Many thanks. Problem Solved

Answer (score 3):

The copy command (at least with Cisco boxes) allows you to specify the username and password all in one line. Something like this:

```
copy running-config ftp://put_user_name_here:put_password_here@put_machie_name_or_ip_here//home/users/some_location/ut-running-config.txt
```

You should be able to use scp or tftp in place of ftp as well.

Comment: Well but I think I will face the same issue on connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with FTP.

First you need to setup the FTP username and password:

```
ip ftp username xxx
ip ftp password xxx
```

Then get your script to do this:

```
show run | redirect ftp://1.1.1.1
```

IOS will then use the local username and password set up before

Comment: Well but I think I will face the same issue on connectivity

Comment: ip ftp source-interface vlan 11 will fix that. That config stays in the running config

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to enable SCP server on the router and script the backup from the other side. Instead of trying to push it it from the router, why not pull it from the backup server? You will have greater scripting flexibility this way.

Comment: I've already thought in this alternative but we have a provisioning system, we can enter commands on a webgui to execute on devices. We would like to perform backup before or after provisioning ports.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider creating an `alias` with this command:

```
alias exec .save copy run tftp://192.168.1.1/file.txt
```

and issue `.save` instead of typing the entire line every time.